# Is there a way how to save json with flask_sqlalchemy with sqlite backend

Tags: json, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to **save data** in form of JSON (returned as result from POST request)

```
def get_data(...):
    ...

    try:
        _r = requests.post(
            _url_list,
            headers=_headers
        )

        return _r.json()
    except Exception as ee:
        print('Could not get data: {}'.format(ee))
        return None
```

Into a table in **SQLITE database** as backend.

```
def add_to_flight_data(_data):
    if _data:
        try:
            new_record = FlightData(data=_data)
            db.session.add(new_record)
            db.session.commit()
            print('Data instertedto DB!')
            return "Success"
        except Exception as e:
            print('Data NOT instertedto DB! {}'.format(e))
            pass
```

This is my simple flask code

```
import os
import time
import auth
import json
import requests
import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# from safrs.safrs_types import JSONType

project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
database_file = "sqlite:///{}".format(os.path.join(project_dir, "2w.sqlite"))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


class FlightData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    json_data = db.Column(db.JSONType, default={})

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

It seems like there is perhaps no option to save JSON in sqlite
`json_data = db.Column(db.JSONType, default={})`

**Please ADVISE**
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you should be using [`db.JSON`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html?highlight=json#sqlalchemy.types.JSON), not `db.JSONType` as there is no such column type in sqlalchemy.

Regardless of that, SQLite has no JSON data type, so sqlalchemy won't be able to map columns of type `db.JSON` onto anything. According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html?highlight=json#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) only Postgres and some MySQL are supported. There is support for JSON in SQLite with the [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html), but sqlalchemy will not be able to make use of it.

Your best bet then is to declare the column as `db.Text` and use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to jsonify the data on write. Alternatively modify your `get_data()` function to check for a JSON response (check the `Content-type` header or try calling `_r.json()` and catching exceptions), and then return `_r.content` which will already be a JSON string.

Use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to read data back from the db.

Comment: The JSON1 support is coming: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3850/request-sqlite-json1-ext-support

Comment: @IljaEverilä: OK that's interesting. Don't know if it will arrive in time for the OP.